# PHP Creating a form procedurally

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking for a form of 681 questions, for that I am using PHP and HTML files on a local Wamp server. The problem is that I cannot receive the data in my database even if it is sent successfully, because without an error message. I generate them using a database and the file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" title="Voir la page d'accueil">Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactform.php" title="Voir la page contact">Bilan Carbone Maquette</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" title="Voir la page contact">Bilan Carbone Prototype</a></li>
</ul>

<h1>Bilan Carbone Prototype</h1>
  

</body>
</html>
// Beginning of Form
 <form class="form" action="tact1.php" method="POST">
 
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bilan carbone";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dataenergieunreperecsv1tableau";
// ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, selection de la dernier ligne
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   //output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        
      echo "<p>Dans la catégorie " . $row["COL 9"]. "pour le poste d'émission :  " . $row["COL 8"]. ".<br>Quelle est la consommation annuel de " . $row["COL 5"]. " " . $row["COL 6"]. " en terme de ". $row["COL 7"]. " ? <br><input type='text' name='question_1' id='question_1' placeholder='Bla Bla Bla bla' ></p>";
    
    
    }

} 
else {
  echo "0 results";
 }
$conn->close();
?>
    
<p class="usersubmit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" ></p>
```

Send of data to the database and manage by this code in the tact1.php file :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" title="Voir la page d'accueil">Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactform.php" title="Voir la page contact">Bilan Carbone Maquette</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" title="Voir la page contact">Bilan Carbone Prototype</a></li>
</ul> 

<h1>Recap CO2e</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

</body>
</html>

<?php 

  //creating connection to database
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bilan carbone") or die(mysqli_error());
  //check whether submit button is pressed or not
if((isset($_POST['submit']))){
  //fetching and storing the form data in variables

    $question_1 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['question_1']);

 }
$question_1 = isset($question_1) ? $question_1 : '';

  //query to insert the variable data into the database
$sql="INSERT INTO test0 (question_1) VALUES ('".$question_1."')";
  //Execute the query and returning a message

if(!$result = $con->query($sql))
{
die('Error occured [' . $con->error . ']');
}
else
   echo "Thank you! We will get in touch with you soon";
    


?>
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why are you testing `isset($question_1)` *after* you assign `$question_1 = $con->real_escape_string(...)`

Comment: Oh ! It's a mistake, i have repaired her and now i have this message: Error occured [Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'question_1' at row 1]

Comment: @LaventureEstivene Is the `question_1` column an INT or VARCHAR, or something else?

Comment: The value is INT !